# Looking for ppa kernel for ubuntu 16.04

Tags: nvidia, kernel, xorg, ppa

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

dose not have any ppa kernels for 16.04. I have stability with current kernel/nvidia. I have frequent system freeze (when switching between VT). The system load jumps up and xorg is at 100 cpu.

Comment: Which kernel are you after?

Answer (score 0):

search for 'xenial' in the list of http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ where you can find this one

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.9-xenial/